# SAP WebIDE local configuration credentials error

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I have configured WebIDE locally on my system using [these guidelines](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/04/21/install-sap-web-ide-locally-for-trial-windows-version).

but when I created the text file holding information about connections, it's not working the exact way as it should have worked.
Below are my connection details:

```
Description=Test7
description Type=HTTP
TrustAll=true
Authentication=NoAuthentication
Name=Test7
ProxyType=Internet
URL=http\://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\:XXXX
WebIDEUsage=odata_abap,ui5_execute_abap,dev_abap
WebIDESystem=Test7
WebIDEEnabled=true
User=test
Password=test
sap-client=XXX
```

but when I am creating a new project it's showing following error:

> Unable to access the selected system. Check your credentials and try again. If the problem persists, check if the OData service is available...
>
> [image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just compared with my text file. I´ve made some changes to yours according to what is working for me. take a try:

## ServiceDestination

Description=Test7

Type=HTTP

TrustAll=true

Authentication=NoAuthentication

Name=Test7

ProxyType=Internet

URL=https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX

WebIDEUsage=odata_abap,ui5_execute_abap,dev_abap

WebIDESystem=Test7

WebIDEEnabled=true

That´s it, I hope it helps. Kind Regards,
Gabriel

Comment: I am still having the same kind of error, can you advise me something related to patches. I feel there are some patches missing in my SAP IDES that need to be configured to manage the connectivity with SAP WEBIDE.

Comment: I haven´t heard of patches for the backend system but there is a configuration you must carried out: the Hana Cloud Connector must allow your HCP with your IDES system. More information here: https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?e6c7616abb5710148cfcf3e75d96d596.html